# 404 Not Found when accessing a Web API method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I need this method to return an integer value:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("ByPayment")]
    public int Payment(string accountId, string mount, string shenase)
    {
        return 21;
    }
}
```

When I go to the following address:

```
http://localhost:1070/api/values/Payment/ByPayment?accountId=258965&mount=85694&shenase=85456
```

I get the following error:

[image: ٍError]

What's the problem? And how can I solve it?

Comment: What kind of name/attributes does the containing controller class have?

Comment: @GWigWam sorry . i cant understand your question

Comment: What is your controller name? Does it inherit from ApiController?

Comment: @CiprianLipan controller name `Values` and No, it not inherit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing you wanted to send Get request with query string parameters.

**1.** Change the 'HttpPost' to 'HttpGet'
`[HttpPost("ByPayment")]` to `[HttpGet("ByPayment")]`

**2.** Also change your request url, Its not correct.

`http://localhost:1070/api/values/Payment/ByPayment?accountId=258965&mount=85694&shenase=85456`

to

`http://localhost:1070/api/Values/ByPayment?accountId=258965&mount=85694&shenase=85456`

Updated code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("ByPayment")]
    public int Payment(string accountId, string mount, string shenase)
    {
        return 21;
    }
}
```

I suggest please read this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) to understand the basic of webapi.

Comment: it return `value` . but i need return `21`

Comment: i add that in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143466/discussion-between-ahmar-and-kianoush).

Answer (score 2):

There could be more reasons why you get the 404. But there is one thing that's definitely wrong - you are sending `GET` requests to a method that's marked with `[HttpPost("ByPayment")]` (which means it only responds to `POST` requests.

I don't know what you intended to do but you either have to change it to `[HttpGet("ByPayment")]` or use a REST client that can make `POST` requests (e.g. [REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/).

Other reason could be that your controller has a wrong name. It should be called `PaymentController`.